# Round cake pan, what's the deep thing going on here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, intuition

There's the following excerpt from my book.

> For example, suppose you have a recipe for an $8$-inch-square cake, but you want to make it round instead. What size of round cake pan should you use? First you perform an abstraction to turn this "real-life" question into a piece of math. We want to find a circle whose area is the same as the area of the given square, which is $8^2$ or $64$. Now we have to remember that the area of a circle is $\pi r^2$ where $r$ is the radius. If we write $d$ for the diameter of the circle (because cake pans are measured by their diameter not their radius), this means we need$$\pi\left({d\over2}\right)^2 = 64.$$Now we actually do the logical reasoning, manipulating the algebra to find out what the diameter $d$ needs to be. This is the only part that's actually math.$$\begin{align} \left({d\over2}\right)^2 & = {{64}\over\pi} \\
> {d\over2} & = \sqrt{{64}\over\pi} \\
> d & = 2 \times \sqrt{{64}\over\pi} \\ 
> & \approx \pm 9.027.
> \end{align}$$

What's the actually deep mathematical thing, deeper intuition going on underlying this calculation, if any? Like, what is the conceptually "correct" way to think about this? I swear there's gotta be something!

Comment: I would dispute the claim that solving the equation is the "only part that's actually math".  To my mind, setting up the equation has as much claim to being "actual math" as solving it, maybe more.

Comment: Also you want $9.027$, not $ \pm 9.027$ (have you seen a cake pan with negative diameter?).  The part where you reject negative solutions is in going from $$\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{64}{\pi}$$ to $$\frac{d}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{64}{\pi}}$$ and not $$ \pm \sqrt{\frac{64}{\pi}}$$

Comment: Just for fun : Do you know that a 8  $cm^2$   cake is more digestible than a 8 $inch^2$    cake (not only for metric system users...) ?

Comment: It's very unclear why you expect there should be something "deeper" going on here, or what you find unsatisfying about the given explanation.  Can you say more about what you're looking for, exactly?

Comment: Um, what are you asking.  The book is giving a real life problem and telling you how to solve it.  There's nothing deeper or less deep than that.  If you understand the explanation you get the deepity.  If you don't then the deepity is doing the math.  I honestly don't understand what more you expect.

Comment: The only deepity is how do you solve for a variable in one equation to equal value for another formula. $f (x)=g (c)$.  Her Area _ square(s) =$s^2$, area _ circle(r)=$\pi r^2$, Diameter(r) =$2_r$.   So what is Diameter (r) if Area_circle (r)=Area_square (8).  That's as deep as it gets.  Roll up your pant cuffs and splash to the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "deeper thinking"

Your recipe is going to make some fixed volume of batter.  If the area of the circular pan is smaller than the area of the square pan, when the pour the batter into the pan, the batter will fill the pan to a higher mark, than it would in the square pan.  And if the area of the circular pan were smaller, it would not fill as high.

If the difference is not too drastic, it is not going to make a big difference in the way the cake tastes.  But, if the difference is significant it will change the cooking times and perhaps the texture of the finished product.

So what is the area of the circular pan? and what is the area of the square pan? and what diameter of circular pan will have the same area as the square pan the recipe calls for?

Area of a square $s^2$

$s = 8$

Area of a circle is $\pi r^2 = \pi (\frac d2)^2$

$\pi (\frac d2)^2 = 8^2$

and solve for $d$